# Pitfall to watch is data dirty in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I get technicalData from REST, then display it. User can add,modify some params. I watch if data get dirty then display button to save. Here is the code:

```
$http.get(someurl).success(function(data){
  $scope.technicalData = data;
});
$scope.technicalData = {};
var unregisterTechnicalDataWatch = $scope.$watch('technicalData ', function(newValue, oldValue){
     if(Object.keys(oldValue).length !== 0) {
        $scope.technicalData._dirty = true;
        unregisterTechnicalDataWatch();
     }
},true);
```

**Do you see any pitfalls of this approach?**

I know there is [FormController](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3aform.FormController) , but I didn't find any good example.

Comment: Didn't find any example? Have you tried the examples at docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms ?

Comment: @Stewie not any. good examples. AngularJS Docs is a nightmare and my fragile soul couldn't handle so unfriendly environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By all means you'll want to avoid that approach.  I'd suggest using a form controller.  Then, you can do something like the following to show/hide a save button when the form has been dirtied:

```
<form name="form" ng-submit="save()">
Name: <input ng-model="name"/>
<button type=submit ng-show="form.$dirty">Save</button>
</form>
```

Check out [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3raVK/).